# Install Support library correctly

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am always getting an error when I try to update the: `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` library and that I have to change something in the Android Manifest file which does not makes any sense to me. How can I install this library correct, without getting an error that I have **different** support library versions. Like this:

> <Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from
> [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
> is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

**OR** like this:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.1.0, 26.0.2, 26.0.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0 and com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.2

How can I avoid these errors?

Comment: please mention other libraries that you are using.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using some other libraries that they include support library themselves.
and their support library version is different from the one you are trying to include inside your project.